# Как изменить переданную аргумент?

Tags: javascript, функции

Хотелось бы чтобы функция изменил переданный аргумент к функции.

Например:

```js
console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
// ["C", "B", "A"];

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);

console.log(arrayValue);
// [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: метод `sort` меняет массив

Comment: @Grundy это намёк такой? (¬‿¬)

Comment: Впрочем, я понял

Comment: @Capital300 Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @PeterKolosov вы неправильно выразились. Если дан ответ который помог решить или решил задачу, то тогда его нужно принять. Ознакомьтесь с тем что такое [принятый ответ в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @ΝNL993 Очень смешно.

Comment: @NNL993 А разве мой ответ не помог решить задачу?

Comment: @PeterKolosov `А разве мой ответ не помог решить задачу?` -- прочитайте мой комментарий внимательно, я нигде не говорю, что ваш ответ не помог решить задачу, я лишь упомянул что вы не правильно выразились в вашем комментарии.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Тогда надо убрать это из списка шаблонных комментариев: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1223/548252

Comment: @PeterKolosov список не официальный, хоть и полезный. Если хотите, меняйте, ответ всё равно общий.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть встроенная функция в JavaScript.

Функция, которая будет возвращать перевёрнутый массив:

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
    return array.reverse();
}
```

Использовать её можно так:

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
    return array.reverse();
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
// ["C", "B", "A"];

let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arrayValue = reverseArray(arrayValue);

console.log(arrayValue);
// [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

let someSwappedArray = reverseArray(["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", "!"]);

console.log(someSwappedArray);
// ["!", "o", "l", "l", "e", "H"]
```

Но я не вижу особого смысла использовать функцию, так как существует встроенная функция в JavaScript `array.reverse`.

Пример с `array.reverse`:

```js
console.log(["A", "B", "C"].reverse()); // тут
// ["C", "B", "A"];

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arrayValue = arrayValue.reverse(); // и тут

console.log(arrayValue);
// [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

---

Замечание.

Функции в JavaScript не могут принимать переменную в качестве аргумента, а потом изменять её в глобальной области видимости, из закрытой области видимости.

Поэтому, в вашем примере кода, если просто скопировать мою функцию и запустить с вашим кодом, второй пример работать не будет.

Поэтому, чтобы заработало, нужно заменить строку в вашем коде:

```js
reverseArray(arrayValue);
```

на:

```js
arrayValue = reverseArray(arrayValue);
```

Также, надо:

- либо изменить название функции при объявлении с `reverseArray` на `reverseArrayInPlace`
- либо везде заменить в вашем коде `reverseArrayInPlace(...)` на `reverseArray(...)` (я рекомендую так сделать)

В вашем коде не очень корректное название функции, поэтому я назвал функцию не `reverseArrayInPlace`, а просто `reverseArray`.

---

Всё это мнение с именем функции ИМХО, вы просто можете скопировать функцию со своим именем, и не изменять:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    return array.reverse();
}
```

и дальше уже вставлять свой код.

---

Если что-то непонятно, задавайте вопрос, буду рад помочь снова.

Comment: `Функции в JavaScript не могут принимать переменную в качестве аргумента, а потом изменять её в глобальной области видимости, из закрытой области видимости.`, если это объект/массив, то вполне могут.

Comment: @OliverPatterson я имел в виду именно **значение переменной**, не _значение из значения переменной_

Comment: Ну а если вам надо именно сложный код, с циклами, переменными, и т.д. я  конечно могу сделать, но это будет непродуктивно, некрасиво, длинно, и медленно. Лучше использовать `array.reverse()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(list) {
 return list.reverse();
}

console.log(reverseArrayInPlace([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: объяснений нехватает